# R correlation coefficient NA even if use= is included

Tags: r, nan, correlation, na, pearson-correlation

I am trying to correlate (pearson) two variable with some missing values. I am aware that I need to include use="complete.obs" in this situation. Here is the format of the command I used:

```
cor(data_frame, use="complete.obs")
```

I am getting NaN as correlation coefficients. I have tried `use="pairwise.complete.obs"` as well, with similar results.

Any advice would be much appreciated! Thank you

Note: I am a beginner in R

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I also had "Inf" values in my data, when I removed these I could get the correlation coefficients.